# Nesting in `Manipulate` and `SetterBar`

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Is there a way (ideally simple) to combing `SetterBar` with other manipulate controls? Such as have a manipulater parameter inside the `SetterBar` definition.

Here I would like to use `m` and `n` to select parts of data set. The first example, I do it manually before manipulate. The second example was my idea how I would like to have `m` and `n` implemented in the `SetterBar` functions. Obviously it does not work since there is cross dependence.

```
data = RandomReal[1, 100];
m = 10;
n = 30;
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[{data[[m ;; n]], 
   d}], {d, {MovingAverage[data[[m ;; n]], 3] -> "MOA", 
   GaussianFilter[data[[m ;; n]], 3] -> "Gauss"}}]
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[{data[[m ;; n]], 
   d}], {d, {MovingAverage[data[[m ;; n]], 3] -> "MOA", 
   GaussianFilter[data[[m ;; n]], 3] -> "Gauss"}}, {m, 1, Length@data,
   1}, {n, 10, Length@data, 1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify, I calculate the averaged data before plotting and use a simple variable to choose the average method:

```
Manipulate[If[n <= m + 2, n = m + 3];
 dma = MovingAverage[data[[m ;; n]], 3]; 
 dg = GaussianFilter[data[[m ;; n]], 3];
 ListLinePlot[{data[[m ;; n]], If[d == "MOA", dma, dg]}]
 , {{m, 1}, 1, Length@data - 3, 1}, {{n, Length[data]}, 2, 
  Length[data], 1}, {{d, "MOA"}, {"MOA", "Gauss"}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use IntervalSlider.

```
Manipulate[
  ListLinePlot[{Take[data, interval], func[Take[data, interval]]}], 
  {func, 
     {MovingAverage[#, 3] & -> "MOA", 
      GaussianFilter[#, 3] & -> "Gauss"}, 
   ControlType -> SetterBar}, 
  {{interval, {1, Length@data}}, 1, Length@data, 1, 
   IntervalSlider, Method -> "Push", 
   MinIntervalSize -> 2}]
```